# System keyboard for Unity Editor/Remoting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I am trying to develop an application which uses the (CPU/GPU) power of the Workstation with the Hololens 2. Therefore I test a lot in the **Unity Editor** or through **Remote Rendering**.

I use the **MRTK Toolkit** whichs displays a **system keyboard when working directly on the Hololens 2**. Of course when I test the application through Unity (Editor and Remote) no immersive system keyboard opens and I have to use my physical keyboard.

**Question**

Does somebody has tried to **show the system keyboard** also **inside the unity editor or during remoting**? Is there an already existing, e.g, flag, which turns this on and that i missed?

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: as you say the `system keyboard` is of the OS itself ... HoloLens overlays it over your running app  -> how should Unity running on your PC know the OS keyboard of the HoloLens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@derHugo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7111561/derhugo) said, there is no option to display the [System keyboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/ux-building-blocks/system-keyboard?view=mrtkunity-2022-05) inside Unity Editor. Where an alternative could be to design your simple keyboard for the purpose of Unity Editor, or you could launch a pop-up OSK (On-Screen Keyboard) when the Input Field is selected ([link](https://gist.github.com/SteefmanV/f9df806f3036020dd8a322edde572dc4) to a script).